# How can I use a key generated with sn.exe to sign a string in php?

Tags: .net, php, cryptography

This is another question in the line of getting C# and PHP to exchange signed pieces of data. In my scenario, I have a signed C# assembly on the client side with a public key. I also have a PHP page on the server with a private key. I want to be able to sign some data in PHP with the private key and check the signature against the public key in C# on the client.

I've figured out how to generate a public/private key file with `sn.exe` (duh). This is the 
format I need for .NET to sign assemblies etc. Once signed, the assembly can provide the public key as a property (something like `Assembly.GetName().PublicKey`)

Also, I've figured out, that I probably want to use the [openssl_sign()](http://ch.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-sign.php) function to create a signature for the data. The example shows reading in a fixed length of bytes from a `.pem` file. This file I don't have.

I guess the `.pem` file is just a way of storing the public / private key information, comparable to the XML and `CspBlob` stuff I can generate with the `RSACryptoServiceProvider`. What is the relation between these formats? How can I convert one to the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To exchange secure information, you should *not* to use private/public pair generated by `sn.exe` as that meant to be used to sign a .NET assembly. Assuming both languages implemented cryptography algorithm correctly, you just need to use same keys (string values) and same algorithm. Can't be that hard =)

Please, take a look here: [Generating Keys for Encryption and Decryption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5e9ft273.aspx) as it contains more information about how you can use public/private keys in .NET side.

Comment: Actually, it is not that easy either. Given a key pair generated by `RSACryptoServiceProvider`, how do you get that into the .pem format expected by PHP?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know exactly how pem/php combination works, but maybe someone else can help